# clone a private repository into windows server

Tags: windows, gitlab

If we want to clone the private repository into windows server

```
- name: hosts
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: create a directory
    win_file:
      path: C:\testing
      state: directory
  - name: clone a private repository into windows server
    win_git:
      repo: http://username:password@gitlabserver/automation/common/ansible/ansible.git
      dest: C:\testing\
      branch: master
      update: yes
      recursive: yes
      replace_dest: yes
      accept_hostkey: yes
      force: yes
      ignore_errors: yes
      register: find_output
  - debug:
      var: find_output.stdout_lines
```

Answer (score 0):

In the inventory we have to give the below:

```
[hosts]
windowsserver.aws.com
[hosts:vars]
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_user=windowsserverusername
ansible_password=windowsserverpassword
ansible_port=5985
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
ansible_winrm_transport=ntlm
validate_certs=false
ansible_winrm_scheme=http
ansible_become=false
```